# Handling business logic before a mutation?

Tags: graphql, hasura

Lets say for instance you’d like to throttle the amount of mutations that are made in a certain amount of time and it doesn’t make sense for it to be in a postgres function or trigger. You wanted to do this for every mutation, how would you approach that in Hasura?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are at least two potential solutions, given the description:

1. De-bounce in the client side. This depends if all the mutations are coming from one client.
2. Create a proxy server in front of Hasura that achieves the rate limiting behavior of your choosing. Do different mutations need different rate limiting rules? Otherwise you may be able to set up some simple page rules in a service like Cloudflare

Do you have more specific examples?